# Why isn't the the line integral over a curve in a 2-dimensional force field zero?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

I'm looking at example 7 in 16.2 of Stewart. If there is a force field $F(x,y)=x^2i - xyj$ that moves a particle along the quarter-circle $r(t)=cos(t)i +sin(t)j$, $0\leq t\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, and you take:

$$F(r(t))=cos^2(t)i-cos(t)sin(t)j$$
$$r'(t)=-sin(t)i+cos(t)j$$

the work done by the force field in moving the particle is apparently given by:

$$\int_CF\cdot dr=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}F(r(t))\cdot r'(t)\,dt = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(-2cos^2(t)sin(t))\,dt = -\frac{2}{3}$$

The line integrals I have been doing up to this point were the type where you have a function and you integrate it along a curve, meaning you evaluate the function $f(x,y)$ along the curve, and the sum gives you the area of one side of a "wall" or some similar shape as it appears in three dimensions.

When you have a two-dimensional force field, and you evaluate a line integral along a curve in this force field, what is the result in a geometric sense, aside from work done? I'm just picturing a line on a plane with no three dimensional function to evaluate; why isn't the integral just the area of the line (zero)?

Comment: Have you looked up line integrals on Wikipedia? [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#/media/File%3ALine_integral_of_vector_field.gif) is an instructive animation.

Comment: @Mark S. that's really helpful. So am I correct in saying that line integrals over a scalar field calculate the area of the "curtain" above the curve on the plane, whereas when a particle moves through a vector field, integrating assigns an "area" to the position of the particle based on which direction it is moving relative to the vector field and takes the sum over the curve? Nothing is coming "out of the page" so to speak. It's just confusing me because while the latter is taking place in a plane, the former is literally a function in 3-space and it's easy to visualize what's happening.